Changestream for mongodb insert operation
Actually i want to use changeStream for my chat application to write on insert operation
  changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
        if (change.operationType === 'insert') {
            res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(change.fullDocument)}\n\n`);
        }
    });

but i am facing many errors The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets
run the command
mongod --replSet "rs0" rso.initiate

but got error

MongoServerError[NoReplicationEnabled]: This node was not started with replication enabled.

can you guide me step by step setting up changestream for normal db
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chatrapidex

Change streams are available for replica sets and sharded clusters: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/
